# Android app crashing for no reason

Tags: android

I'm new at android developing. I'm trying to make a simple drumset app, when you click on specific drum, it plays specific sounds, it isnt finished yet, but I cant understand why is it crashing all the time. Please help me. Here's the code:

```java
package com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class DrumSetActivity extends Activity { 
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        MediaPlayer ridesound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ridecymbal);
        MediaPlayer hatsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highhat);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ImageView ride=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upLeftPlate);
            ride.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ridesound.start();
                }
            });

            ImageView highHat=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.midLeftPlate);
            highHat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    hatsound.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drumset" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/upLeftPlate"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/kh" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/midLeftPlate"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upLeftPlate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what LogCat say:

```
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset/com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset.DrumSetActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset.DrumSetActivity.<init>(DrumSetActivity.java:12)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514):  ... 11 more
```

and can someone please tell me why is it taking so long to upload my 90KB app on the emulator?

```
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] ------------------------------
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] Android Launch!
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] Performing com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset.DrumSetActivity activity launch
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'bulat'
[2011-11-17 21:10:36 - DrumSet] Uploading DrumSet.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-17 21:13:37 - DrumSet] Installing DrumSet.apk...
[2011-11-17 21:13:51 - DrumSet] Success!
[2011-11-17 21:13:51 - DrumSet] Starting activity com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset.DrumSetActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-11-17 21:13:54 - DrumSet] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.stiggpwnz.drumset/.DrumSetActivity }
```

3 minuts between uploading and installing a 90KB thing. Why?

Comment: it says alot of things that, and I dont get any of it, how can I send the logs to you?

Comment: press the red 'E' button and look at the red text, it actually shows classes, methods and lines and even tries to say what kind of error occured, so it is the tool #1 to use

Comment: you may just post the whole red text

Comment: You can do a shift+click over all of the ERROR lines, hit ctrl-c to copy, then paste in here.

Comment: done, this logs just freak me out

Comment: It's a normal LogCat for an error, don't worry :)

Comment: Something is not instantiated Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 11-17 20:55:56.349: E/AndroidRuntime(514): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)

Comment: btw, there is always some reason for application to crash.

Comment: "Something is not instantiated" what does it mean?

Comment: "btw, there is always some reason for application to crash" you mean I'll never be able to run this thing? :D

Comment: He means it doesn't crash "for no reason" like you said in the title. It crashed for a reason you don't know, this is not the same thing :) Find the reason, fix it, and it'll work

Comment: but I cant find any logical reason to this, maybe because I know so little about all this android stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/playing-sound-effect-using-mediaplayerotice) ,
notice the comment below, this may be your problem. Your are not following proper calling hierarchy of media player.
Go through the [state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) of media player.

And here is complete [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.html) of Media Player (Playing audio).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the point in adding an answer that just says another answer is correct and doesn't add anything else? You should have upvoted him instead

Comment: @NizamutdinovAdel I have edited my answer above, this will surely help you know....

Answer (score 1):

The logCat says an exception is raised when trying to initialize your activity. The cause is there's a `NullPOinterException` when getting resource from the `MediaPlayer`.

To me, that means that either one of `R.raw.ridecymbal` or `R.raw.highhat` doesn't exist. Check their case and make sure they're actually present (probably the first one if I count the lines correctly: it says line 12).

Comment: then have you tried moving the two MediaPLayer lines inside the onCreate method of your activity, after the setContentView line?

Comment: yeah, I did it, but it keeps crashing

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to move these two:

```
MediaPlayer ridesound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ridecymbal);
MediaPlayer hatsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highhat);
```

to be after *setContentView();*

**Edit:**
The problem could be that you are trying to reference MediaPlayer before it is actually referenced by the Activity itself, or you are trying to set some result to the component that is not yet referenced

Comment: what do you mean? im not trying to do anything illegal :D
and yeah, I moved those, it keeps crashing
Im not doing anything besides the code above

Comment: ok, i tried the layout on my comp. everything is ok, so I assume the problem is with the MediaPlayer references

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the MediaPlayer on the onCreate not before so change this two lines in:

```
      MediaPlayer ridesound; 
      MediaPlayer hatsound;
```

and on the onCreate you instantiate the MediaPlayer

```
     ridesound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ridecymbal);
     hatsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.highhat);
```

you've better follow the androidtutorial of mediaplayer because you have to rewrite all your code... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html